# Print Job delay when using IPP for Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, printing

I'm using [IPP](https://npmjs.org/package/ipp) (and [CUPS](http://www.cups.org)) with Node JS to print labels (DYMO Labelwriter 450 Turbo's) from our child check-in system. I need to print differing quantities (var `qty`) of each label depending on which room the child is in (1-3). Currently I'm creating a new IPP print job for each label - but there is a few seconds' delay between printings.

Is there a way to pass quantities to IPP with each job to eliminate the delay? Or perhaps pass multiple of the same .pdf into a single job?

Vars `pdf`(the generated label - using a [.pdf template](http://cr8.me/u/label_b187.pdf)), `qty`(quantity of label that need to print) and `pid`(Printer ID of which printer to print to) are passed to the following bit of code:

```
function print(qty, pid, first, last, gender, room, notes, notesr, timestamp, age, grade, code) {

    fs.readFile('label.pdf', 'utf-8', function (err, pdf) {

        pdf = pdf.toString();
        pdf = pdf.replace('<FIRST>', first).replace('<LAST>', last).replace('<GENDER>', gender).replace('<ROOM>', room).replace('<NOTES>', notes).replace('<NOTESON>', notesr).replace('<TIMESTAMP>', timestamp).replace('<AGE>', age).replace('<GRADE>', grade).replace('<CODE>', code);

        if (err)
            throw err;

        var printer = ipp.Printer('http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/DYMO_'+pid);
        var file = {
            'operation-attributes-tag':{
                'requesting-user-name': 'Test User',
                'job-name': 'My Test Job',
                'document-format': 'application/pdf'
            },
            data: new Buffer(pdf, 'binary')
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
            printer.execute('Print-Job', file, function (err, res) {
                console.log('Printed: '+res.statusCode)
            })
        }
    });
}
```

**Update:**

It looks like my problem is that [CUPS waits for the printer to return to "idle"](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7004646) before it begins processing the next job - thus creating the delay between jobs. An [option](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.3/network.html#IPP), `waitprinter=false` needs to be added to the DeviceURI to bypass the wait.

I've tried adding it to the DeviceURI in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` with no avail. I've tried adding it to the `Printer` object url like:

```
var printer = ipp.Printer('http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/DYMO_'+pid+'?waitprinter=false');
```

Which errors that *printer cannot be found*. How do I use this option with IPP?

**Update #2:**

Out of urgency, I created a work-around using [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org) to generate multi-page label pdf's on the fly and sending all of the family's labels as a single print job.

Comment: By the way, the label quantity is no longer a concern. I decided to create 3 pdf templates "label1.pdf","label2.pdf","label3.pdf" - and that fixes the speed between identical labels as I can send them all through a single job. My concern now is in the updated section: using an option, `waitprinter=false` with the DeviceURI. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to globally configure the `waitprinter` option in a .conf file?

Comment: What did / does your `/etc/cups/printers.conf` configuration look like, with the addition of the `waitprinter=false` to the URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried adding it to the DeviceURI in `/etc/cups/printers.conf` on the CUPS host?

If you did it by simply editing that file while CUPS was running, it will not work. *Normally*, `printers.conf` is not meant for directly editing. It does state this in its first lines (screaming '*# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING*').

## 1.

The recommended way to change the printer configuration *permanently* is by using the `lpadmin` command on the CUPS server:

```
lpadmin -h cupsserver -P printername -E -v ipp://11.2.13.14:631/waitprinter=false
```

The CUPS server will then tell the CUPS clients that this printer is accessible to them via

```
http://cupsserver:631/printername
```

(Should you really need to directly edit the printers.conf, you have to stop the CUPS daemon first, make your edit, and then restart cupsd.)

## 2.

To change the printer configuration *temporarily* (for the next job only), you can pass the option with the `lp` command when sending the job:

```
lp -d printername -o waitprinter=false myjob.pdf
```

Translated into your problem space, this solution means:

1. Do not try to change the printer name in your `var printer = ipp.Printer ...` statement.
2. Instead rather change operation-attributes-tag and add a `'waitprinter': 'false'` statement there.